# Set titles to mutliple instances of jquery combobox

Tags: jquery, html, combobox

I am using jQuery combobox three times in a page. By default the combobox item has the title `Show All Items`, but I need 3 different titles for my comboboxes. How can I do this?

I saw one option to change the title in code like the below:

```
attr("title", "Show All Items")
```

How can I give a title? Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you not change the HTML the plugin is based on, or the configuration of the plugin?

Comment: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/demos/autocomplete/combobox.html
This is what i used.I want to use it for 4 drop downs.For country,city,state ,town.So my titles will be different.In this its given " Show All Item".Any solution like passing parameters in combo box for creating different titles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how this can be done.

Firstly, add the default value for the title in options object and pass the actual value to _createShowAllButton function in _create. The code should look like below.

```
$.widget( "custom.combobox", {
   options:{
      title: "Show All Items"
   },
   _create: function() {                                
      this.wrapper =$( "<span>" )                                        
      .addClass( "custom-combobox" )                                        
      .insertAfter( this.element );  

      this.element.hide();                                
      this._createAutocomplete();                                
      this._createShowAllButton(this.options.title);                        
   },
   ...
```

Update the _createShowAllButton so that it uses the passed in parameter instead of the hard coded value, as shown below.

```
_createShowAllButton: function(dynamicTitle) {                                
   var input = this.input,                                        
   wasOpen = false;  

   $( "<a>" )                                        
   .attr( "tabIndex", -1 )                                        
   .attr( "title", dynamicTitle)
   ...
```

Finally, pass the title that you want to set.

```
$( "#comboboxCountry" ).combobox({title: "Select Country"});
$( "#comboboxState" ).combobox({title: "Select State"});
$( "#comboboxCity" ).combobox({title: "Select City"});
$( "#comboboxTown" ).combobox({title: "Select Town"});
...
```